# AWK - Extracting the last syllable of words

Tags: awk, gawk

I have to extract the last syllable of several words.

The words will always end in a consonant.

The possible consonants are these: "b c cs d dz dzs f g gy h j k l ly m n ny p q r s sz t ty v w x y z zs"

The possible vowels are these: "a o u ö ü e i á ó ú ő ű é í"

Given this word, "vélem**ény**" , I have to extract **ény**

Given this word, "otth**ion**", I have to extract **ion**

Given this word, "felad**at**", I have to extract **at**

I have made this function, which will return the position of the last vowel.But what if two vowels together?

```
function extrac(arr1,arr2,x1)
{
    # arr1 - array-vowels "a o u ö ü..."
    # arr2 - array-word divided into letters
    # x1 - length-arr2

    for (ix=x1; ix>0; ix--)
    {
        for (jx=1; jx<=14; jx++)
        {
            if (arr1[jx] == arr2[ix])
            {
                return ix;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

IN

```
vélemény
otthion
feladat
```

Desired output:

```
vélemény    ény
otthion    ion
feladat    at
```

Comment: Well `([aouöüeiáóúőűéí](?:b|c|cs|d|dz|dzs|f|g|gy|h|j|k|l|ly|m|n|ny|p|q|r|s|sz|t|ty|v|w|x|y|z|zs))(?:\s|$)` works...

Comment: @Thomas You are using the ternary operator, but I don't know how to apply it to extract what I need. Could you give me an example of use with one of the words?

Comment: You mean `?:` by *ternary operator* ?

Comment: The regex you can use is [`[aouöüeiáóúőűéí]+(?:[cz]s?|d(?:z(?:s)?)?|[glnt]y?|sz?|[bfhjkmpqrvwxy])[aouöüeiáóúőűéí]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/vO1lD0/3) but I have no idea how it can work in awk.

Comment: OK, It's a regex. That's not going to be useful for me. What I need is something similar to my function.

Comment: After you find the last vowel, reverse direction until it's not a vowel. (You  may also want to have a plan in case you get a word with no vowels.)

Comment: @EdMorton otth**io**n it's in my example

Comment: Why regex will not be useful for you ...?

Comment: @Thomas A regex outside of the context of a specific tool is never useful since every tool has it's own flavors of regex it can support and it's own caveats wrt delimiters and contents (e.g. backreferences). In this case the regex you proposed uses some constructs (`\s`) that are only supported in GNU awk but more importantly other constructs (`?:`) that aren't supported in any awk. Firefly - the `?:` in this case isn't a ternary operator it's a look-behind (or ahead or something) operator as defined in PCREs, not supported in EREs as awk uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'match($0,/[aouöüeiáóúőűéí]+[^aouöüeiáóúőűéí]+$/,a){print $0, a[0]}' file
vélemény ény
otthion ion
feladat at
```

The above uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(). With other awks it'd be:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/[aouöüeiáóúőűéí]+[^aouöüeiáóúőűéí]+$/){print $0, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file
vélemény ény
otthion ion
feladat at
```

With some awks you might be able to use Equivalence Classes instead of listing each possible variation of each vowel:

```
/[[=a=][=e=][=i=][=o=][=u=]]+[^[=a=][=e=][=i=][=o=][=u=]]+$/
```

but Equivalence Classes aren't supported in GNU awk.